# Pbs with python tempfile.mkdtemp in gitlab-ci docker

Tags: python-2.7, docker, gitlab-ci

Running a simple unittest from `gitlab-ci.yml` I get this error::

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_save_plots_in_one_file (tests.test_plots.TestPlotUtilities)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builds/r_d/prod/tests/test_plots.py", line 66, in test_save_plots_in_one_file
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 339, in mkdtemp
    _os.mkdir(file, 0700)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpivScxU'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 184 tests in 19.584s
```

The unittest::

```
 def test_save_plots_in_one_file(self):
     path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
     tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
     ...
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that this depends on the Docker image that you've been using - perhaps post the YML file too? I'm thinking that the `tempfile.mkdtemp()` command has failed. There's the possibility that the `/tmp` directory isn't writable in the image you're using.

Comment: Have you manually checked for the file? Seems it doesn't exist - at least, not there.

Comment: The file in question is the directory that is suppose to be created by tempfile.mkdtemp(). I don't know how to check inside the docker execution of gitlab ;(

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: I'm also running into the same issue. In my case, the temp directory I'm trying to access is a subdirectory of a volume mounted directory into the running container. But I'm running as root in the container, and using the :z in the volume mount. The directory is owned by root when I create it manually, from inside the container. But I'm unable to create it through python tempfile.mkdtemp().

Comment: Turns out my app was running as a user I didn't expect. I figured this out by adding this line: os.mkdir('/tmp/test2') to the script.